# Didselectrowatindexpath navigation based on login

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

In a side menu tableview there are 3 sections. The value of one row in the second section depends on the login.

Case1: User A Logs in, items in 2nd Section are `iAdmin`, `Dashboard`, `Tickets`..etc

Case 2: If User B logs, items in 2nd section are `Dashboard`,`Tickets` etc.
i.e `iAdmin` wont be available in 2nd section if user B logs in

The issue is: I need to navigate to a particular page when i click on Tickets inspite of whichever user logs in

Here is the code for it :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {


    if indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==2
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TicketsViewController") as! Tickets


        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        self.present(controller,animated: false,completion: nil)


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below solution.Hope this will help you.

```
   //Define a enum
    enum sectionItems:String{
        case iAdmin, Dashboard, Tickets
    }
    //Variable to hold section row types
    var section2Rows:[sectionItems]!


//Initialise section 2 rows based on the user type - In viewdidload
if userType = "User A"{
    section2Rows = [.iAdmin, .Dashboard, .Tickets]
}
else if userType = "User B"{
    section2Rows = [.Dashboard, .Tickets]
}

//in tableview did select use index to identify the row clicked 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 2{
        //Access the selected row
        if section2Rows[indexPath.row] == .Tickets{
            //Do your logic
        }
    }
}
```